# CountDownTimer is not cancelled

Tags: android

**I define the countdowntimer here.**

[image]

Then, new countdowntimer is defined for this variable in an onclick method:

```
   public void showQuestion(int questionNumber){
    questionTimer = new CountDownTimer(10500,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            remainingTime.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            remainingTime.setText("0");
            showCorrectAnswer();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Then i cancel this timer on another button' onclick method;

```
    public void selectOption(View view) {
    questionTimer.cancel();
    }
```

In this time, it is succesfully cancelled. Then i am doing the same again. showQuestion method is working in the same way.

```
   public void showQuestion(int questionNumber){
    questionTimer = new CountDownTimer(10500,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            remainingTime.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            remainingTime.setText("0");
            showCorrectAnswer();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

It is started succesfully. When i want to cancel this timer on another button onclick method, it is not working. Not any error. I hope it could be clear. Thank you so much.

Comment: Make sure your `onClick` method of second `Button` is working properly.

Comment: i am sure about it because i use the same button to cancel when i make the the first cancel.

Comment: add questionTimer = null; after you cancel

Comment: Are you calling the correct instance of the timer to cancel it in the second one?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is the timer can be started multiple times (sometimes not intentional) before the first timer is finished or cancelled. In that case, when you try to cancel it, you can only cancel the first timer. To solve this issue, you only have to check whether the timer is running, if it is running, wait for it to finish or cancel.

Define a global parameter:

> Boolean timerRunning = false;

```
   public void showQuestion(int questionNumber){
    if (timerRunning) return;
    timerRunning = true;
    questionTimer = new CountDownTimer(10500,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            remainingTime.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            remainingTime.setText("0");
            showCorrectAnswer();
            timerRunning = false;
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Your selection option method can be changed to below: check if the timer is null before cancelling it.

```
public void selectOption(View view) {
    if (questionTimer != null) questionTimer.cancel();
    timerRunning = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void selectOption(View view) {
    questionTimer.cancel();
    questionTimer = null;
}
```